# How to clear the data usage?

Tags: data-monitoring

I'm using Android KitKat. I'm not able the clear the data usage of mobile data (Mobile) as well as Wi-Fi. Is there any option to clear the data usage in rooted and non-rooted Android devices?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Data usage Mobile and Wifi]

Somebody Please do help. Am using Non-rooted Android Device.

Answer (score 10):

On a rooted device, go to `/data/system/netstats/` and delete all the files there. Reboot the device and the data history would be gone. Worked on Android 4.2.1 and 5.0.2, and [maddisonj](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/237467/maddisonj) and [Beygi](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/262243/beygi) reported it works on 4.4.2 and Android 8.0 as well. It clears both SIM data as well as of Wi-Fi.

This would not reset the current cycle you would be having. I believe `/data/system/notification_policy.xml` manages it, so you can edit it out if that cycle also bothers you.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge; image order: before and after deleting the files)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

On a non-rooted device, factory reset seems to be the only choice.

Comment: [Somebody noted that](http://kacnje.blogspot.in/2013/07/reset-data-usage-on-android.html?showComment=1394617126703#c7254403787874112475), on Android ICS, the correct way is `adb shell; su; rm /data/system/netstats*.bin; sync; sync /data/system; sync /data/system*;` Then do a [tag:hard-reboot].

Comment: I'd like to let everyone know that this also works on Android 8

Answer (score -3):

You just have to do that disable your app then enable again all the data usage history will reset automatically

Comment: No it will not, please do some research before you post answer

Comment: Apart from which: How do you disable a user-installed app? And how do you disable something like "Android system" if it comes to that? So even if that were true, it's not feasible.