# How to display/obtain detailed app data usage of last 24h?

Tags: mobile-data, data-monitoring

I know Android has a nice built-in way to visualize the monthly data usage on a daily basis. It also displays the cumulative data transfered data per app per cycle (1 month).

Where are the data usage numbers stored internally? And how detailed are they? More specifically, I am trying to figure out **which app consumed data in the last X hours** (or between timestamp A and timestamp B). Something ate up all remaining prepaid data last night (oddly while I was on WiFi and with background data restricted).

Comment: You've seen the vertical bars in *Settings › Data Usage* and that you can use them to restrict stats to e.g. those 24h?

Comment: @Izzy Yes, I've seen the vertical bars. How do you restrict them to a specific period? The phone I'm looking at is running Android 5.1.1

Comment: I'm moving them left or right (tap-and-hold, then move), until exactly the wanted period is covered.

Comment: Hmm that does not work for me. I can only move a horizontal data warning bar up and down.

Comment: Funny. I cannot test with 5.1.1 (no matching device). Try grapping them at their "lower end" (directly on the X axis) – won't work if grabbed "in the middle". Also, tapping the X axis should reveal their resp. markers to make them easier to handle.

Comment: Yeah really odd. I think I know what you mean, and I'm pretty sure I have seen it before, but it's just not there on this device. Thanks though.

Comment: [`/data/system/netstats/`](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/120915/96277) is the place to look for, if only you've got root access. The maximum data you officially can get is from [`adb shell dumpsys netstats detail`](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/netstats.html).