# How to export data usage stats?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, data-monitoring

I am able to see the stats generated by Android at `Settings>Data Usage` for cellular data and wifi both. Is there any way to export these stats?

I don't think android has any option for the extraction. I know apps which track data, but they wont give me historical data.

Where is this data stored, maybe, I can extract it from there.

My phone is Moto G5S, running 7.1.1, not rooted.

Comment: [adb shell dumpsys netstats detail full](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-platform/TSf81eXT5Jo) - I don't think they are stored for ever. `batterystats.bin` gets refreshed on reboot / full charge

Comment: Please ignore the storage part and what follows after that. Somehow I was thinking of battery stuff

Comment: See [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120915/131553) for where it may be stored

Answer (score 3):

You can save data usage recordings using an ADB command like the following:

```
adb shell dumpsys netstats detail full > data_usage.txt
```

If you are interested in the data usage of a specific application, you can find its identifier (which is used in the above recordings) using a command like the following:

```
adb shell dumpsys package com.example.application | grep userId
```