# Clearing Wifi Data Usage Statistics

Tags: samsung, root-access, data-monitoring

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy Tab S8 Ultra and I have been trying to
clear the "Wifi Data Usage" statistics in the setting menu.

[image: Wifi Data Usage Stats Page]

It seems like there was someone that asked the same thing 7 years ago.
[How to clear the data usage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120874/how-to-clear-the-data-usage)

However, this method seems outdated.
I was not able to find any files to delete in the /data/system/netstats directory.

[image: Screenshot_20221215_224010_Total Commander.jpg]

I've tried different file manager applications, including termux, to see if there were any files, but It was empty.

I'm in a situation where I have to frequently clear the statistics, so doing a factory reset every time is not a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why this method will not work on rooted phone as well.

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Select **Connections** (Internet/Networks)
3. Select **Data Usage** (towards the bottom)
4. Select **Billing Cycle and Data Warning** (Data Warning and Limit)
5. Select **Start Billing Cycle on**
6. Select Today's Date and press **Set**

Comment: I accidently deleted my original comment haha
Still, thank you for your comment.
However, that option is not available for my tablet.
When I go into "Data Usage", The only thing I can click on is "Wi-Fi data usage" and that's it.
That option is visible on my phone though.
I am guessing it's because my tablet is a wifi only model.

Comment: I tried on tablet, as you say, its not there.  I will leave the answer there for others seeking the solution for a phone.

Comment: It's weird why it's like that... Thank you for your help though